# Using Videoview or mediaplayer to play http live streaming video is LAG

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

First,I built a small app using videoview to play hls video with mp4 format on Samsung galaxt S2.With SD quality, video was smooth.But with HD quality,video was lag. Then, I built a larger app to play hls video using same videoview or mediaplayer android. When i played video, video was lag with SD and HD quality.

In small app, I have a string array to store URLs. My app allows user to choose a URL and push a button to throw a activity to play video using videoview:
Code using videoview in the small app :

```
        VideoView vd = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
        mc.setAnchorView(vd);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(URL_link);
        vd.setMediaController(mc);
        vd.setVideoURI(uri);
        vd.start();
```

In larger app, I using listfragment to display all URls. User choose a URLs, then throw a activity to playvideo using videoview. Code in the activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_channel_detail);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvVideoPlayer);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        channel_id = extras.getInt(ChannelDetailActivity.CHANNEL_ID);
    }
    tv.setText("Video is playing...");
}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getChannelInfo();
}
private void getChannelInfo( ) {
    TimeTVApiCaller.getInstance().getChannel(channel_id, this,
            new AjaxCallback<ChannelInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void callback(String url, ChannelInfo object,
                        AjaxStatus status) {
                    if (object != null) {
                        Urlvideo = object.getChannelUrls().get(0).getPath();
                        getURLfull(Urlvideo);
                    }
                }
            });
}
    //get a full URL
protected void getURLfull(String url)
{
    TimeTVApiCaller.getInstance().getChannelStream(url, this, new AjaxCallback<String>()
            {
               @Override
            public void callback(String url, String object,
                    AjaxStatus status) {
            String Urlfull = object.replace("\"", "");
            Urltoken = Urlfull;
           //Using the same videoview
            VideoView vd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(ChannelDetailActivity.this);
            mc.setAnchorView(vd);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse(Urltoken);
            vd.setMediaController(mc);
            vd.setVideoURI(uri);
            vd.start();
            //vd.requestFocus();
            }
            });
}
   }
```

I have two questions :

1. Why videoview or mediaplayer play hls video is lag?
2. How to custom videoview or mediaplayer to play hls video smoothly?

Answer (score 0):

Each segment in HLS aka [HTTP Live Streaming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming) is typically 10 seconds.

The player measures the time it takes to get each segment, if it took too long it will try to pick a bandwidth where it can get a segment or more before it plays it. And the most common error is buffering delays.
You should look in the log file to see what the player is doing when playing content.

If the above is not helpful, [this](http://www.longtailvideo.com/blog/31646/the-pain-of-live-streaming-on-android/) might help.

Comment: Sorry, I can`t. Bit try this url and see if it`s better http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

Comment: If you would like to follow HLS standards, the content type of the media should be in the format of m3u8. m3u8 is supported by Android 3.1 and above.

Comment: of cources, my format url is .m3u8. You right! Lag is buffering delays. But with mobiles have high performance. Videos isn't lag. So. You know a reason why?

Comment: I find that HLS performance varies wildly across different Android devices and versions. Try [Vitamio](http://vitamio.org/) library, it allow you to use HLS feeds.  Have not tried it myself

Comment: My problem is loading buffer too long, it take over 10s. How to custom buffer to play video fastest. i want player to load the lowest bitrate and load a 1-2s segment but not a 10s segment at first. Then, player start load the adaptive birate and a 10s segment. Can you help me?

Comment: Didn't Vitamio work? I don't know if you can do that, you have to do it in the source. "You have to encode the source into multiple files at different data rates and divide them into short chunks, usually between 5-10 seconds long. These are loaded onto an HTTP server along with a text-based manifest file with a .M3U8 extension that directs the player to additional manifest files for each of the encoded streams."

Comment: Tried this and it worked just fine on my HTC One running 4.3.
`VideoView vd = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
       vd.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"));                
       vd.setMediaController(new MediaController(MainActivity.this));
       vd.requestFocus();              
       vd.postInvalidateDelayed(100);  
      new Thread(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
        vd.start();
       }
      }).start();`

Comment: My source is multi bitrates. but when video starts, it plays  the highest bitrate.i want to play the lowest bitrate at first

Comment: You can do that with [www.wowza.com/](http://www.wowza.com/) by creating a smil file. 
`<smil>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <switch>
            <video src="myStream_700" system-bitrate="700000"/>
            <video src="myStream_350" system-bitrate="350000"/>
            <video src="myStream_200" system-bitrate="200000"/>
        </switch>
    </body>
</smil>`

Answer (score 0):

I assume HD quality is at least 720p and more than 1.5 mbps bit stream with h.264/avc encoding. My best guess is that S2 Hardware doesn't support it.